# How to remove the setter from a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, setter, getter, getter-setter, defineproperty

Consider the following code:

```
var x = 0;

var o = {};

function getter() {
    return x;
}

Object.defineProperty(o, "y", {
    get: getter,
    set: function (y) {
        x = y;

        Object.defineProperty(o, "y", {
            get: getter
        });
    },
    configurable: true
});
```

My objective is to remove the setter and make the property `o.y` non-configurable after the setter has been called once. However it doesn't work as expected:

```
> x       // 0
> o.y     // 0
> o.y = 1 // 1
> x       // 1
> o.y     // 1
> o.y = 2 // 2
> x       // 2
> o.y     // 2
```

So my code did not work as expected, and I can't think of any other solution. Hence this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think of the redefine operation like this: each key in the new definition replaces the corresponding key in the old definition.  Since you do not specify a `set` key when you redefine the property, it retains its old value.

You need to explicitly include it as `undefined` in order to get rid of it, and in fact you don't need to set the getter at all because you are not changing it:

```
Object.defineProperty(o, "y", {
    set: undefined
});
```

Then, in my tests:

```
o.y     // 0
o.y = 1
o.y     // 1
o.y = 2
o.y     // 1
```

Comment: I reckon this is the trick that makes all sort of inner React objects (e.g. `nextProps`) unmodifiable.

Comment: @MarcoFaustinelli Set the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty -- there's a "writable" property