# How to remove only setter JS?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter, delete-operator

I've just read about getters/setters in JavaScript.

As the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set#Removing_a_setter_with_the_delete_operator) writes:

> If you want to remove the setter, you can just [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) it:
>   `delete o.current;`

This code removes the setter...

```js
var object = {
  something: "",
  get property() {
    return this.something
  },
  set property(value) {
    this.something = value
  }
}

object.property+="1"
object.property+="2"
object.property+="3"
object.property+="4"

console.log(object.property) //"1234"

delete object.property

console.log(object.property) //undefined
```

... but the getter (with the same name) too.

I need to use the same name to use the `+=` operator.

So the question:

**Is there a way in JS to remove a setter, but keep the getter?**

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the setter from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173591/how-to-remove-the-setter-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: what would you expect the getter to do in that case?

Comment: @DanO In this case, it simply returns `object.something`. It's just an example, in my original code it's more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) (with `{set: undefined}`) for this purpose:

```
Object.defineProperty(object, "property", {set: undefined})
```

This will remove only the setter.

```js
const object = {
  something: "",
  get property() {
    return this.something
  },
  set property(value) {
    this.something = value
  }
}

object.property += "1"
object.property += "2"
object.property += "3"
object.property += "4"

console.log(object.property) //"1234"

Object.defineProperty(object, "property", {set: undefined}) //delete setter

console.log(object.property) //"1234"

object.property += "5" //setter missing, fails silently

console.log(object.property) //still "1234"
```

Comment: This doesn't work if attempting to remove the setter from within the setter

Comment: @TreverThompson Why would it not? It does work that way too.

Comment: Not sure perhaps. It wasn't working for me, I resolved it in a different way

Comment: @TreverThompson That's OK. This works for me though: https://codepen.io/FZs111/pen/zYLqzQd?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

```js
var object = {
  something: "",
  get x() {
    return this.something
  },
  set y(value) {
    console.log(value);
    this.something = value
  }
}
console.log(object.x)
object.y = object.x + "1"
delete object.y
object.y = object.x + "2"


console.log(object.x) //"1234"

delete object.x

console.log(object.x) //undefined
```

You have to change the name of setter and getter.

```
object.y += "1"
```

It don't make sense,  because you recall the same function and it'll become:

```
object.y = object.y + "1";
```

It's wrong.

```
object.y (set) = object.x (get) + "1";
```

Better now. No?